# How to print html source to console with phantomjs

Tags: html, web-crawler, phantomjs

I just downloaed and installed phantomjs on my machine. I copy and pasted the following script into a file called hello.js:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'https://www.google.com'

page.onLoadStarted = function () {
    console.log('Start loading...');
};

page.onLoadFinished = function (status) {
    console.log('Loading finished.');
phantom.exit();
};

page.open(url);
```

I'd like to print the complete html source (in this case from the google page) to a file or to the console. How do I do this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Spent some time to read the documentation, it should be obvious afterwards.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://google.com', function () {
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: this would give the html from the dom (which has been manipulated by javascript and has undergone some level of syntax correction) as opposed to the raw unprocessed html served by the server. Is there a way one can get that? maybe from onResourceReceived?

Comment: Hey AriyaHidayat! is it also possible to receive the css with phantomjs? I didn't see anything about that yet

Comment: how to authenticate user & pass over https @toom

Comment: Hi, @Ariya Hidayat : not working in my case. Tried with my website and another : 
http://www.nolme.com
https://www.centrale-canine.fr/lofselect/chien-ws/1/
page.content is empty or just header. Did I miss something ?